# Dynamically populating a dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I remove all the  values from a dropdown list using jQuery?

```
idnum = "item-7";
```

which populates a dropdown with 7 items.  I could have an "item-3" which would populate a dropdown with three items.  What I'm trying to do is select a button which could have an id value of "item-X" where X is the number of entries to populate so it could be different based on whatever button I click.  I want to clear the select list and repopulate it with a different number on each button click.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#items').empty();

 // alert('I was clicked, my id is ' + $(this).attr('id')); 
 var idnum = $(this).attr('id');
 var pos = idnum.lastIndexOf("-");
 var num = idnum.substring(pos + 1);

 // alert("You have " + num);

 // var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
 var numbers = new Array(num - 1);

 for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   numbers[i] = i + 1;
 }

 for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){ 
   $('<option/>').val(numbers[i]).html(numbers[i]).appendTo('#items'); 
 }
```

I tried empty() and remove() and they're both not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#items').html('');
```

will clear your options.

Comment: I made <select id="items"> and it worked. Could you post your html as well?

Comment: sorry for the comment, you're correct.  It did work.  That's what working at 1:15 am does to you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to populate with new option don't use `appendTo()`.

```
var opt='';
for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){ 
   opt += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
}
$('#items').html(opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove your options, you can also do :

**$('#items > option').remove();**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#items').children().remove();
```